# Based on a parent list Divide a tuple into sublists having all the elements in the resultant list of the parent list

Tags: python, list, sorting, tuples, combinations

I have two lists

```
parent_list = ['a', 'b', 'c']
list2 = [33.33, 38.33, 43.33, 48.33, 53.33, 58.33, 63.33, 68.33, 73.33, 78.33, 83.33, 88.33, 93.33, 98.33]
```

The sample of my expected output is given below

```
[[('a', 33.333333333333336),('b', 38.333333333333336),('c', 43.333333333333336)],
 [('a', 38.333333333333336),('b', 38.333333333333336),('c', 38.333333333333336)]]
```

Its a Cartesian product of both the lists but removing the list if the 1st element of tuple is repeated in the list and each list should have all the elements of the parent list.

To do this. I am doing

1. Cartesian product

```
def cartesian_product(list1, list2):
    return list(product(list1, list2)) 
    
all_combi = cartesian_product(parent_list,list1)
```

2. Making combinations

```
from itertools import combinations
combi = itertools.combinations(all_combi, 3)
combi = list(set(combi))
```

3. Removing unwanted lists.

```
final=[]
for i in combi:
    # Using set
    seen = set()
      
    # using list comprehension
    Output = [(a, b) for a, b in i if not (a in seen or seen.add(a))]
    Final.append(Output)
    
print(Final)
```

4. Removing lists less than size of 3 elements

```
new_list=[x for x in Final if len(x)>=3]
```

I am looking for a more optimized way of achieving the desired output.